# How can I toggle a the visibility of a DIV element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying toggle a DIV element using jQuery, a good example of this implemented is clicking the sign up button on [Udemy.](https://www.udemy.com/)

I've implemented something similar using jQuery but I'm sure that to gain the effect I'm looking for, I will have to use JavaScript but its just that I'm don't know how to use JavaScript.

The my implementation be seen in my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0ajpd9go/), I've initially set the div to `display:none` and used jQuery to show the div on button click.
As you can tell with the fiddle, it displays with an enlarging animation instead of just appearing (not sure how to change this) and i'm only unable to make the div disappear by again clicking the button.

Also, how would I go about implementing functionality to make the div disappear by clicking anywhere on the screen?

Thanks to anyone in advance for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Please remember that jQuery is JavaScript, jQuery actually **written in JavaScript**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you face is that a click on the button is also a click on an area where you would like the pop up to disappear, if it's already shown. Because events bubble, the button click would make the pop up appear and then the document click (which fires after this because of bubbling) would make the pop up immediately disappear.

To solve the problem, you must stop a click on the button from bubbling to the rest of the document as well. You do this with:

```
  event.stopPropagation();
```

So, what you need to do is make sure that when the button is clicked, the click event doesn't bubble up to the document, where you will have already set up a click event handler that makes the pop up go away:

```
 $(document).on('click', function(event) {
   // We want to hide the pop up, but not if you click on 
   // the pop up itself - - anywhere else, but not the pop up
   if(event.target.id !== "pop-up"){
      $('#pop-up').hide();
   }
 });
```

See this fiddle for a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/0ajpd9go/8/

Answer (score 1):

If you want your div to just appear on the screen change this line:

```
jQuery('#pop-up').toggle('fast');
```

to this:

```
jQuery('#pop-up').show();
```

Maybe you'd like to give bootstrap modal a try:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `$.fn.toggle();`
`$.fn.toggle();` toggles the visibility of an element meaning if the element is visible then it will be hidden when toggled and if the element is hidden it will be shown when toggled.

Here is a basic (animation free) example of using toggle:

```
$(".button-that-toggles").on("click", function() {
  $(".div-to-toggle").toggle();
});
```

Your box toggles with an "enlarging animation" because you used `$.fn.slideToggle();`

There are three default ways to toggle using jQuery (toggle, fadeToggle and slideToggle)

Here is an example of toggling a element using `$.fn.fadeToggle();`:

```
$(".button-that-toggles").on("click", function() {
  // NOTE: 250 represents the duration of the animation, meaning that the animation will last 250 milliseconds.
  $(".div-to-toggle").fadeToggle(250);
});
```

Here is an example of toggling a element using `$.fn.slideToggle();`:

```
$(".button-that-toggles").on("click", function() {
  // NOTE: 250 represents the duration of the animation, meaning that the animation will last 250 milliseconds.
  $(".div-to-toggle").slideToggle(250);
});
```

Also here is an example of how you can hide your div by clicking anywhere on the page:

```
// listen for a click anywhere in the page
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  // make sure the element that was clicked is not your div
  if(!$(event.target).is(".your-div")) {
    // you can now hide your div
    $(".your-div").hide();
  }
});
```

Also please remember that jQuery is JavaScript as a matter of fact jQuery is a library **written in JavaScript**.